# Client status of order between dates

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to figure out a client's status on the date of order. A client is able to place an order even though their account is "paused" and it is common that a client will "flip flop" between active and paused multiple times.

Clients table with a list of status's and the date I which a client status was updated.

```
client_id         status         created_at
     101          active         09/03/2019 
     101          paused         12/24/2018       
     101          active         10/08/2018  
     102          paused         03/14/2020       
     102          active         01/08/2020 
     103          paused         09/21/2020    
     103          active         05/18/2020
```

orders table:

```
client_id          order_date          qty
   101             10/08/2018           1
   101             01/09/2010           1
   102             04/30/2020           2
   102             05/08/2020           1
   103             09/20/2020           1    
   103             09/22/2020           1  
   103             09/24/2020           1
```

Desired result, a left join on the orders table with client status if order was made between created_at date for status change.

```
client_id          order_date          qty        status
   101             10/08/2018           1         active
   101             01/09/2010           1         paused
   102             04/30/2020           2         paused
   102             05/08/2020           1         paused
   103             09/20/2020           1         active
   103             09/22/2020           1         paused
   103             09/24/2020           1         paused
```

I've tried:

```
select *
from orders o
left join clients cs
on cs.client_id = o.client_id and cs.created_at < o.order_date
```

I'm getting duplicate entries reasonably but can't see to figure it out. Any advice would be great! Pretty new to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) here:

```
SELECT *, (
  SELECT status
  FROM clients cs
  WHERE cs.client_id = o.client_id
    AND cs.created_at < o.order_date
  ORDER BY cs.created_at DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS status
FROM orders o
```

This fetches the last status update before the order date for each order.